# Unity 2D topdown bow rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a bow in my game that follows the direction of my mouse.
There are many tutorials also showing how it is done and they are all quite the same.
The issue is that the cursor has to rotate around a center which is not the game object. It is better visible in video: https://streamable.com/iyhz87
And yes, I am sure that my game object is actually not moved down to where the cursor is.

This is the code I am using:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ + offset);
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail?

Comment: The idea is just to move the bow to wherever the cursor is so I can shoot arrows in all directions. The center is just the player but the object is seperat. The newest tutorial I was following was this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9Ed7OhSXVI&t=531s

Comment: To move the bow to wherever the cursor is? So you can just assign its `position` to mouse position in world space, can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rotation or lookat code for the bow is working perfect, what u might be facing is some sort of offset error, try setting the position of the bow transform some units above to fix the pivot at the centre of the sprite.. to be exact the offset would be something like , Vector3(0,spriteHeight/2,0); and add it to wherever you are making the bow transform follow the player transform..

or if the bow is **child** of the **player** try this code and see:

```cs
void Start(){
    offsetY = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.rect.height / 2;
    this.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,offsetY,0);

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ + offset);
}
```

Upvote and accept the answer if it works

Comment: Well the bow object itself does not contain a sprite renderer. It works by having an empty object in the center and a child object with the sprite which then rotates around the parent with an offset. You are still right about the offsetY though. Changing the y-Position of the bow object by 0.07 units makes the bow actually rotate around the player